# HTML/CSS bakcground around page and image peeping out of the page

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to solve the problem showed on the picture.

I have a site of a width of 980px (margin:auto) centered in the middle of the page and I need surrounding background of a width of 400px each side. But when user narrows the width of the browser the background shouldn't affect horizontal bar (only the width of the page itself 980px)

Plus there's an image which is placed 80% in the main page and the rest outside of the page. I also want this piece of the image (20%) not to affect the horizontal bar when user narrows the width of the window.

THANKS!!!
image:
http://tinypic.com/r/ri58io/8

code: `link to fiddle`https://jsfiddle.net/c0ro66s4/

Comment: Can u show us the code

Comment: Some css and html will be more helpful.

Comment: I don't have the code here but it's something like this https://jsfiddle.net/c0ro66s4/

Answer (score 0):

The thing with this design is that the 'background' boxes have a fix width. When the fill the rest of remaining width (next to the content) no scrollbar appears (at least, not in Firefox).

So what I've did is made a media query. When the screen size is bigger than (980+400+400=) 1780px the boxes will have their normal width. As soon as the screensize becomes under the 1780px, the width will be set to auto and we use the 'left' position, which makes them fill the screen and won't show the scrollbars.

I made the testcase in JSFiddle with half the sizes (otherwise it wouldn't fit on my screen).

```
<div id="content">Content</div>
<div id="bgLeft"> </div>
<div id="bgRight"> </div>
```

```css
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 100%; }
#content {
    background: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 490px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -245px;
}
#bgLeft {
    background: lightgreen;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 245px;
    height: 100%;
}
#bgRight {
    background: lightgreen;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 245px;
    height: 100%;
}
@media screen and ( max-width: 890px ) {
    #bgLeft {
        width: auto;
        left: 0;
    }
    #bgRight {
        width: auto;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Set the image as background in both boxes and a align the one in the left box on the right and the one in the right box on the left.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/08wm163g/)

**EDIT**
Added your background-images: [**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/08wm163g/1/)

Comment: Thanks a MILLION times! Would it also work with the image getting out of the "main" page #contect? thanks!

Comment: Sould it be 80% inside of the content box or the body? What happens with the other 20% on screen resize? Or should it only show 80% whatever the screensize.

Comment: Yes it should only display that part that's inside

Comment: Sorry!! It should display the WHOLE image but when the user resizes the window it should only display the part inside of the screen..just like the background it shouldn't affect the horizontal bar

Comment: inside of the #content